# Redirect with extra parameters in URL

Tags: angular

I have Routes defined in my app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    .
    . 
    .
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

Now in one of my Component, based on a condition I want to redirect to HomeComponent and pass extra parameters in the URL like /home?redirect=1

```
    if( condition ) {
         this.router.navigate(['/home?redirect=1'] ); 
    } else {
         this.router.navigate(['/home'] );
    }
```

However it is not working. Could you please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add params like that:

```
let params: { 'redirect': 1}
this.router.navigate(['/home'], {queryParams: params})
```